# Is there a way to intercept and block image loading from <img> elements?

Tags: javascript, html

#### Background

I have created a Javascript decoder for the [FLIF](http://flif.info) image format. Since it's a new format and browsers don't support it yet (if ever), we want to create a poly-fill for it in JS.

We have one basic version [already working](https://uprootlabs.github.io/poly-flif/polyflif-sample.html). It queries for `canvas` elements and renders the FLIF image on to it.

However, for users that don't have Javascript enabled, the solution doesn't work. They see a blank canvas.

#### Question

We were wondering if there is a way to allow `<img>` elements to be specified in the HTML as a fall-back, but block them from loading via javascript, so that we can replace them with our FLIF canvas?

I have tried adding various event listeners, such as `DOMContentLoaded`, and removing the `<img>` elements in them, but by that time it is too late; the browser starts fetching the image.

Comment: Do you need to avoid the fallback image request? Or is it enough to avoid the image being showed?

Comment: Will this webpage target average users?

Comment: @sergioFC Ideally, would like to avoid the request, to save bandwidth. Though I am curious about "avoiding the image being shown". Perhaps it might lead to my ideal solution, so please add it as an answer.

Comment: @LGSon Yeah, this is meant to be a general purpose poly-fill for all types of websites, until the time browsers support the format natively.

Answer (score 2):

You can't block an existing `<img>` tag from making the request for the resource set in `src` simply because the element has to exist before you can target it with script and by then the request has been made.

Note: Since 99% of the web requires script enabled anymore you could wrap the `<img>`'s  in [`<noscript>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/noscript) tags

Answer (score 2):

You cannot stop a standard image element from being requested in this case, as it's necessary to know that such an element exist before you can access it. Although you can remove/hide/etc the element as soon as possible, from the users end the image would of never been shown. For example:

```
<img id="foo" src="..." />
<script>
   document.getElementById("foo").remove();
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could place the `<img>` tags inside a [`<noscript>` block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/noscript).

I just did a test with Chrome, and it doesn't try to load the images inside the block (unless Javascript is disabled, of course). I don't know if every browser works the same way, though, some of them might still try to download the images.

Comment: That's a neat idea. However, most people who block JS do it with extensions such as `NoScript`, `uBlocker`, etc, where the `noscript` tag doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

I find this a bit hacky, but another choice is to add some extra info to the img tags, and then add some CSS from your poly-fill to avoid the images being showed.

Example HTML:

```
<img src="image.png" data-polyflif-src="image.flif">
```

Example CSS generated inside the poly-fill:

```
// Add CSS to avoid images marked as flif being showed
document.write("<style>img[data-polyflif-src]{display:none;}</style>");

// Once DOM is loaded generate the canvas element and content after every img tag (optionally remove the img or whatever)
...
```